# Hadoop multi-cluster stuck in map reduce process

Tags: linux, hadoop, mapreduce

I installed and configured Hadoop by following instructions in these links:

- http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/
- http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/

Master and slave nodes are communicating with each other, but my job is stuck.

I get following output on my console:

```
runing job id : ....
map %50 reduced %0
map %100 reduced %0
map %100 reduced %16
```

I waited for 15- 20 minutes, but there was no progress.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you give some more context - what MR job are you running? Are you using custom Writable types as your Key / Value, how much data are you processing?

Comment: Looks like something wrong in your reducer logic.If you can put your code here it will be easier to help

Comment: I am using wordcount in hadoop examples. The file size is btween 30 mb to 640 mb